# jQuery remove highlight only if already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

This should be a very basic fix. Im wanting to remove the selected class from when clicking on an already highlighted button. I would like for only one button to be highlighted at any given time.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wy7sjm5/1/

The reason I have the remove class for all of them to execute first is because when one is clicked, I would only like for that one to be highlighted, and not have the previous clicked ones still highlighted. And when clicking on the same button that is already highlighted, would like to remove the highlight. Hope this makes sense.

```
$(".details-btn").on("click", function(){
var $this = $(this);
//Add/Remove selected for button
$(".details-btn").removeClass("selected");
$this.toggleClass("selected");});
```

Possibly using .each() to cycle through each instance of the button and if it has class then remove?  Ive tried different approaches and none are working the way I want.

Comment: I dont understand what you want. In the fiddle, only one button is `selected` at a time. Is the remaining issue to remove the `selecect` on a button when you click it twice?

Comment: Precisely.  You can check out the live version of what I'm trying to accomplish at www.drewcook.net/rockies

Comment: if none of the answers work or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help when I get on tommorow morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can make use of [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Basically, remove the `.selected` from all `.details-btn` except the current one with `not(this)`. Then, use `toggle()`

```
$(".details-btn").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".details-btn").not(this).removeClass("selected");
  $this.toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```js
$(".details-btn").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".details-btn").not(this).removeClass("selected");
  $this.toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
thead {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
td {
  width: 140px;
}
.details-btn {
  background-color: #dad1ea;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 4px auto;
  border: 1px solid #4b3575;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4b3575;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Data</th>
      <th scope="col">View</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <p class="details-btn">+</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <p class="details-btn">+</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <p class="details-btn">+</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>
        <p class="details-btn">+</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <p class="details-btn">+</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>
        <p class="details-btn">+</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect!  I knew it would be something simple like this.  Great thinking.  Much appreciation.

Comment: For few elements here it might not be a problem, but it's worth keeping in mind that `.not` can reduce performance for large sets of elements when called very often. But as said, for a regular use case it's a much more elegant solution compared to mine.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoGrešak.  I will keep that in mind if and when I start working with large data sets.  In this case, I am working with one lineup for each game, which will grow to 180 or so.  Would that be considered large?  Ive written 5000 lines for the index.html file.

Comment: This size probably won't affect you. One thing you can to begin with optimization is store reused values, such as `$(".details-btn")`, in a variable outside the function. Or you could store currently selected item and use stored value to remove class, then replace it with `$(this)`. But I'd say try it first and optimize if you really determine that it's actually this part that is slowing everything down.

Answer (score 1):

Store class state before removing, then add it if it wasn't added before. [Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khobnnxt/2).

```
// Store class state.
var hadClass = $(this).hasClass("selected");
// Remove classes from all elements.
$(".details-btn").removeClass("selected");
// If there was no class before removing, the class will be added, otherwise if
// there was a class before, the class will not be added again.
if (!hadClass) {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
}
```